# getClass().getResourceAsStream() in maven project

Tags: maven, resources

The pom.xml of my maven project looks as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
   <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
   <resources>
    <resource>
     <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
   </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

In the src/main/resources directory I have a file called test.
In the src/main/java directory I have a class that contains the following line:

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test"));
```

When the line of code is run within Eclipse, I get as output

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream@1cd2e5f
```

When I export the project as .jar and run it I get as output

```
 null
```

Did I configure anything wrong?

Comment: Is the class a unit test or a real productive class? I assume a productive class. Than you have to change the getResourcesAsStream("test") into getResourcesAsStream("/test");

Comment: @khmarbaise you are right... but why is it working with eclipse ???

Comment: Is this test resource located in the *src/main/resources* folder or in *src/test/resources* folder with or without package name? Furthermore you don't need to configure the *src/main/java* nor the *src/main/resources* folder, cause they are default in maven.

Answer (score 16):

I was facing this same problem.

When you are trying to get the resource like this: 
`getClass().getResourceAsStream("test")`

You are trying to find the resource relative to that package.

To get the resource from the `src/main/resources` directory, you have to put a slash before the resource name. 
`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test")`

Comment: Wow I wasted 2 hours before finding this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Under `<build><resources>` make sure to have the `<include>` as  below
This will explicitly tell maven to fetch these files and include it in the build.

```
   <build>
     <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
     </resources>
     ...
  </build>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error but through ton of Googling, I could not find the solution.
All the answers are about the path, nobody cares that It can run in Eclipse but not in exported jar file :(

But now I found solution, so simple:
In Eclipse right click on your maven project-> Properties -> Java build path -> Source Tab

You can see a tree like :

```
MyProject/src
   Ouput follder..
   Included (**/*.java)
   Excluded
   ...
```

Double click on `Included (**/*.java)`, remove the existing one so It become `Included (All)`
Now export the jar file :)